# AS3 - for (... in ...) vs for each (... in ...)

Tags: actionscript-3, loops

The following code does the exact same thing. Is there a difference between `for each` and `for (... in ...)`?

```
var bar:Array = new Array(1,2,3);    

for (var foo in bar){
    trace(foo);
}

for each (var foo2 in bar){
    trace(foo2);
}
```

Comment: More like "for (... in ...) vs for each (... in ...)"

Answer (score 76, accepted):

No, they do *not* do the exact same thing.

The output of your for..in loop is

```
0
1
2
```

While the output of your for each..in loop is

```
1
2
3
```

A for..in loop iterates through the **keys/indices** of an array or **property names** of an object. A for each..in loop iterates through the **values**. You get the above results because your `bar` array is structured like this:

```
bar[0] = 1;
bar[1] = 2;
bar[2] = 3;
```

Answer (score 15):

Some of the confusion here is that you are using numbers in your array.  Let's switch to strings and see what happens.

```
var bar:Array = new Array("x", "y", "z");    

for (var foo in bar){
    trace(foo);
}

for each (var foo2 in bar){
    trace(foo2);
}
```

Now your output is:

```
0
1
2
x
y
z
```

As you can see, **for-in** loops over **indexes** (or keys), and **for-each-in** loops over **values**.