# Flex3 issue to get the array format using json object

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

```
{"object":[{"cyclename":"PE cycle","avgRunTime":"05:30","actualStartTime":"08/27/2011 02:40:08","actualEndTime":"08/27/2011 05:26:38","startTime":"02:40","status":"G"}]}
```

this is my file and i want to parse it to array and get the status displayed but i am getting data like `[object object][object Object],[object Object],[object Object]` etc...

how do i parse it to a dataprovider and code i have written is

```
private function cycle_resultHandler(event:ResultEvent):void
{

   var myData:Object = JSON.decode(event.result as String);

   for(var i:String in myData['object'])
   {

     dProvider.addItem(myData['object'][i]);

   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your looping seems to be a bit off.  First off you may want to reconsider your usage of a "for ...in" loop vs. a "for each" loop.  This article:  [for...in vs. for each](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7137596/as3-for-in-vs-for-each) explains the differences quite plainly.

You may also want to give this article a read for more information on [object introspection](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf61c8a-7fe8.html) (a technique for determining the properties of a class at runtime -- what you are trying to do...).

In any case, the issue here is *what* you are looping over.  If the goal here is to loop over the property *values* of "object" and add them to an array or arraycollection, you're almost there--

utilizing a "for each" loop you might do this instead:

```
private function cycle_resultHandler(event:ResultEvent):void {
    var myData:Object = JSON.decode(event.result as String);
    //Here we are iterating over the values in the "object" object as opposed to it's keys.
    for each(var str:String in myData['object']) {
        dProvider.addItem(str);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps :)